# Creating an UNDO flow for transacted fields

Tags: goinstant, goangular

I've been thinking about the applications for goangular.  In the need for immediate storage/database updates, such as a chat application or stocks application etc., I can see how goangular can be extremely useful in the sense of SignalR methodologies.  But could it be applied to the traditional form with ten fields and a save button on it?  All I could think of, was the traditional form, with ten fields on it -less the save button.  If all ten fields are on the scope of the controller, than there would be no need for a save button.  Every change of a field would be commemorated to the goinstant storage.  Now having said that, how would one UNDO lets say any changes to those ten modified fields?  Control+Z ten times?  Not so robust.  Any ideas on a UNDO all Changes button for such a form? (desperately trying to expand the bonds of real time database transactions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'll attempt to answer what I believe to be the spirit of your question first.*

Most of the time, when using GoAngular, we're focused on synchronizing application state.  Aka: Active clients sharing session data.  Inevitably we drift into the territory of long-term persistence.  At this point, rigorous validation / sanitization become a necessity, which we can't discuss without some context.

Let's say our user is completing their profile.  This profile will be used to create a User model, which we will persist.  Now that we have context, it becomes clear that we shouldn't persist a partially complete form, because it wouldn't represent a valid User model. We persist the form once it is complete, and valid.

Implementing this is as simple as creating a custom $scope.onSubmit method and validating the form input before calling `$save` on our new `$scope.user` model.

Undo would be easy to implement too, if you use `$scope.users.$add`, a key will be generated and returned, you could use this key to remove the new user.  If you wanted to roll-back a change, you'd need to implement some system for versions,  and roll back to the previous version of that User.

Hope I've answered your question in here somewhere :)

Comment: Thats the Perfect Answer!

Comment: Any chance for examples? :)

Comment: How about I do you one better, I gave a talk on this subject matter at Google a few weeks ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHbWRFpbma4 

That talk includes links to various examples in this repo: https://github.com/mattcreager/talks/tree/master/realtime-angular-model

If you need a softer on-boarding let me know and I'll create a simple example, might be a couple of weeks though, I'm about to head south for my wedding :)